# Windows RT 8 - view files in application storage

Tags: c#, xml, windows, windows-8

So I'm writing an xml file to the local Storagefolder

```
using Windows.Storage;
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

And i would like to view this file in the Windows Explorer for debug purposes.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is located under

`C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Packages\*application specific letters and numbers*\LocalState`

You can easily determine the path by exploring the `Path` property of your `localFolder` object.

Answer (score 0):

All your application data are in \Users\\Appdata\Local\Packages.
Choose your application, and go in the LocalState folder.